# Heat equation forward finite difference method MATLAB

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, heat-equation

my code for forward difference equation in heat equation does not work, could someone help? The problem is in Line 5, saying that t is undefined, but f is a function with x and t two variables. How should I define t? Thanks!

```
function w=heatfd(xl,xr,yb,yt,M,N)
% input: space interval [xl,xr], time interval [yb,yt],
%        number of space steps M, number of time steps N
% output: solution w
f(x,t) = exp(t-x);
f=@(x) exp (-x); 
c_1 = exp(t);
c_2 = exp(t-1);
l=@(t) c_1*t;
r=@(t) c_2*t;
D=1;                               % diffusion coefficient
T = yt - yb;
h=(xr-xl)/M; k=T/N; m=M-1; n=N;
sigma=D*k/(h*h);
a=diag(1-2*sigma*ones(m,1))+diag(sigma*ones(m-1,1),1);
a=a+diag(sigma*ones(m-1,1),-1);    % define matrix a
lside=l(yb+(0:n)*k); rside=r(yb+(0:n)*k);
w(:,1)=f(xl+(1:m)*h)';             % initial conditions
for j=1:n
  w(:,j+1)=a*w(:,j)+sigma*[lside(j);zeros(m-2,1);rside(j)];
end
w=[lside;w;rside];                 % attach boundary conds
x=(0:m+1)*h;t=(0:n)*k;
mesh(x,t,w')                       % 3-D plot of solution w
view(60,30);axis([xl xr yb yt -2 2])
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `f(x,t)=exp(t-x); f=@(x) exp(-x)`?  The second part looks like you're defining a function of one variable, `x`, but the first part is nonsense.

Comment: The first part is the original function, and the second part is the function at initial condition, where $t=0$.

Comment: You can't reuse the letter f for two different things. For the first thing you called f, you need @ notation.

Comment: Similarly you can't use t like you have used it here, you need a vector of t values to build things like your BCS and such.

Comment: @Ian I tried to use F for the first function, but it is still wrong. And t is the same thing, should I use another notation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the later parts of your code, but the obvious issues are corrected up to this point.

```
function w=heatfd(xl,xr,yb,yt,M,N)
% input: space interval [xl,xr], time interval [yb,yt],
%        number of space steps M, number of time steps N
% output: solution w
u=@(x,t)= exp(t-x); %not sure you actually use this for anything...
f=@(x) exp (-x); 
l=@(t) exp(t).*t;
r=@(t) exp(t-1).*t;
```

Note that the c_1 and c_2 variables were completely superfluous. Also note that you needed .* because you plugged vectors directly into l and r (rather than using a loop). You also seem to be using some conventions that arise from the symbolic toolbox, such as declaring functions with f(...)=... notation. Stop doing that; only use symbolic toolbox conventions if you're using symbolic toolbox utilities (such as symbolic differentiation).

Comment: I am supposed to find boundary conditions, so I use $c_1$ and $c_2$ to represent them. Should I just delete them?

Comment: @J.doe The functions l and r are your boundary condition functions. Your $c_1,c_2$ were just auxiliary functions to represent them that you didn't really need.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!